# What distinguishes a duoplasmatron from simpler methods of ionizing gases?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics

I've been looking at duoplasmatron designs and am not sure what makes the basic function of a duoplasmatron different from simply ionizing H2 gas by sending an arc discharge/electric current through it. As far as I can tell, the only differences seem to be the inclusion of an intermediate electrode and magnetic field (produced by a solenoid) to constrict the arc discharge. Is this correct, or are there other qualities that distinguish this from a simple ionization of a gas?

This is the duoplasmatron design I'm looking at: https://www.iitk.ac.in/ibc/Ion_Sources.pdf

Comment: For a good ion source you need to (1) make the ions, and (2) get them out of the plasma and heading down your beamline. So compare the duoplasmatron vs just a hot cathode spewing electrons in all directions.